# \newcommand throws error: Runaway Argument? Paragraph ended before \lstKV@OptArg@@ was complete

Tags: macros, listings

I'm using the `listings` package in a document.
In order to simplify the use of the `\lstinline` command I created a new command that looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\lstcs}[1]{\lstinline[language=[Sharp]C,breaklines=false]#1}
```

And I've also tried:

```
\newcommand{\lstcs}[1]{\lstinline[language=[Sharp]C,breaklines=false]{#1}}
```

Obviously, I'm using this command to list C# code inline.
This is my sample document where I get the exact same error message:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\lstcs}[1]{\lstinline[language=[Sharp]C,breaklines=false]#1}

\begin{document}

This is \lstcs{CSharpCode()}.

\end{document}
```

The error message reads like this:

```
Runaway argument?
CSharpCode(). 
./test.tex:8: Paragraph ended before \lstKV@OptArg@@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.8 

? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### simple group (level 1) entered at line 7 ({)
### bottom level
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 7 was incomplete) </usr/local/texlive/2012/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11039 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and I haven't used `\newcommand` before and I assume that's where the problem is.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks
— Chris

Comment: The problem is `[language=[`. There you have the same delimiter `[`, so _listings_ assumes that `language=` is the content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It gets confused when it sees the closing `]` too early after `Sharp` so you need to enclose it with an adiitonal pair of braces. Also needs another pair of braces around `#1`

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\lstcs}[1]{\lstinline[language={[Sharp]C},breaklines=false]{#1}}

\begin{document}

This is \lstcs{CSharpCode()}.

\end{document}
```